# Cannot create jQuery function. "uncaught type error"

Tags: jquery

When using this code for my form which I want to slide down once I click it...

```
<script>

(function(){            

        $('html').addClass('js');

        var contactForm = {

            container: $('#contact'),

            config: {
                effect: 'slidetoggle'
            },

        init: function(){
            $('<button></button>', {
                text: 'Contact me'
            })
                .insertAfter('article:first')
                .on( 'click', this.show );
            }, 

                show: function(){
                    contactForm.close.call(contactForm.container);
                    contactForm.container[contactForm.config.effect](500);
                },

            close: function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('<span class=close>X</span>')
                    .prependTo(this)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        $this.hide();
                    })
            }


        };

        contactForm.init();


    })();



</script>
```

...gives me this error in the console:

> "Uncaught TypeError: contactForm.container[contactForm.config.effect]
>   is not a function".

I have no idea what is going on. Would somebody help me? Thanks in forehand.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The `effect` value should be `"slideToggle"` not `"slidetoggle"`

That would produce equivalent of:

```
$('#contact')["slideToggle"](500);
```

The error would be equivalent to calling:

```
$('#contact').slidetoggle(500);
```

and no such method exists

Comment: Thanks alot!! That totally went over my head.